# pygame TypeError: Rect argument is invalid

Tags: python, sockets, server, pycharm

I have read many threads with the same issue as me, but haven't found any that solve my problem, so have decided to ask here. I am currently following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McoDjOCb2Zo). At 1:01:58, when he runs he gets no error, but I receive the error in the title above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/networkTutorial1/client.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/networkTutorial1/client.py", line 78, in main
    redrawWindow(win,p,p2)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/networkTutorial1/client.py", line 54, in redrawWindow
    player2.draw(win)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/networkTutorial1/client.py", line 22, in draw
    pygame.draw.rect(win, self.colour, self.rect)
TypeError: Rect argument is invalid
```

Many websites mention ensuring that self.rect and self.colour are both tuples, and I'm pretty certain that they are, so don't know what's causing the problem.

The code for my client, server and network py files, respectively, are:

```
import pygame
from network import Network

width = 500
height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")

clientNumber = 0

class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, colour) :
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.colour = colour
        self.rect = (x,y,width,height)
        self.vel = 3

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.colour, self.rect)

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += self.vel

        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

def read_pos(str):
    str = str.split(",")
    return int(str[0]), int(str[1])

def make_pos(tup):
    return str(tup[0]) + "," + str(tup[1])

def redrawWindow(win,player,player2):
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    player.draw(win)
    player2.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    run = True
    n = Network()
    startPos = read_pos(n.getPos())
    p = Player(startPos[0],startPos[1],100,100,(0,255,0))
    p2 = Player(0,0,100,100,(0,255,0))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        p2Pos = n.send(make_pos((p.x, p.y)))
        p2.x = p2Pos[0]
        p2.y = p2Pos[1]
        p2.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()

        p.move()
        redrawWindow(win,p,p2)

main()
```

```
import socket
from _thread import *
import sys

server = "192.168.1.72"
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    str(e)

s.listen(2) #max clients on server
print("Waiting for a connection, Server Started")

def read_pos(str):
    str = str.split(",")
    return int(str[0]), int(str[1])

def make_pos(tup):
    return (str(tup[0]) + "," + str(tup[1]))

pos = [(0,0),(100,100)]

def threaded_client(conn, player):
    conn.send(str.encode(make_pos(pos[player])))
    reply = ""
    while True:
        try:
            data = read_pos(conn.recv(2048).decode())
            pos[player] = data

            if not data:
                print("Disconnected")
                break
            else:
                if player == 1:
                    reply = pos[0]
                else:
                    reply = pos[1]

                print("Received:", data)
                print("Sending:", reply)

            conn.sendall(str.encode(make_pos(reply)))
        except:
            break

    print("Lost connection")
    conn.close()

currentPlayer = 0
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to:", addr)

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, currentPlayer))
    currentPlayer += 1
```

```
import socket

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "192.168.1.72"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.pos = self.connect()

    def getPos(self):
        return self.pos

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass

    def send(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(str.encode(data))
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
```

Thanks for spending the time to read this question and help me out.

Comment: Please repeat [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the intro tour.  Extract only the code needed to reproduce the problem; give us that with a values trace and the full error message.

Comment: @Prune, I have included all of the code as the files all interact, and thus could influence the code that causes the error. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about this specific structure to know how to cut the content down, because server.py is required to run before client.py can be run, but client.py references network.py also. According to that link, references files should be included in case the error is in an unexpected location. As for Values trace and error message, I am not sure what you mean, as I have copied over the text in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a `read_pos` before `n.send` on line 67, problem fixed now. I have encountered another issue, but will open a new question as this one is solved.